# ios- view controller doesn't load in current orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using a subclass of UINavigationController to manage rotations for my app.

```
@implementation rotatingNavigationController


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.topViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}
```

In my first view I only allow portrait orientation:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I push to a new view controller using a push segue created in the storyboard. The new view controller supports all interface orientations:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

The new view controller ALWAYS loads in portrait, no matter what orientation the device is held in. If I physically turn the device to portrait mode and back to landscape after the view loads, it rotates correctly. How can I correct this, I need the view to load in whatever orientation the device is held in when the view loads?

Comment: Since iOS6 I had a lot of problems with differently orientated view controllers inside UINavigationController, and no adequate solution has been found. I just try to avoid that and present landscape view controllers modally.

Answer (score 0):

When you are push the newcontroller. check the interfaceorientation of statusbar then:

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   if(isPushingViewVC)
      return NO
   return YES;
}
```

And

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if(isPushingViewVC)
    {
        switch ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)
        {
            case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                break;
            case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
                break;
            default:
                return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
                break;
        }
    }
     return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```